# Swap two items on clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swap

I want to select two elements and when I click the button element I want them to swap place, how would I do that? I've searched and looked for similar answers, but most of them only swap the element up or down.

I'm thinking something like:

```
$('button').click(function(){
   $('#item 1 .selected-item').removeClass('.selected-item').appendTo('#item2');
   $('#item 2 .selected-item').removeClass('selected-item').appendTo('#item1');
});
```

But I don't know how to start, it should look something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tLNAh/1/ (my fiddle)

Comment: In your fiddle which items do you want to swap?

Comment: Have you looked into HTML5 draggable?

Comment: I want to switch two li items that I have selected, the ones that gets the .selected class, and then when I click on the button again, they swap place. #Jez D - no, because I want it in javascript only :) no other libraries, thanks

Comment: You can use Jquery UI Sortable - http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Actually I'd prefer a straight Javascript version, without jQuery, but since I'm not that good, I wouldn't know how to do it only in pure Javascript, that's why I was thinking about jQuery since it's easier for me to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your markup do this:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $('.selected').insertBefore($('ul:eq(1) li:first'));
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tLNAh/2/)

Or you can update to this:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
   if($('.selected').closest('ul').index() < $('.selected').closest('ul').siblings('ul').index()){
      $('.selected').insertBefore($('ul:eq(1) li:first'));
   }else{
      $('.selected').insertBefore($('ul:eq(0) li:first'));
   }
});
```

#### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLNAh/7/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if I wanted to make it so I only can select two list items and then swap with a click on the button again? Because I have to keep the texts that pops up, for easy use on people who doesn't know the software or appplication.

Comment: Only problem is that the list items keeps jumping into eachothers unordered lists :/

Answer (score 2):

try this.
http://jsfiddle.net/tLNAh/3/

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $first = $(".selected:eq(0)");
    $second = $(".selected:eq(1)");
    var tempText = $first.text();
    $first.text($second.text());
    $second.text(tempText);
    $("#instructionText").text("Instructions: choose an item");
});
```

Comment: Not if you need to actually exchange elements instead of text content (it won't work if your items contain other html elements).

Comment: i wrote this to give you an idea. You have to update code for your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Chk this : [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ankittyagi/tLNAh/9/)

Provide id to your ul :

```
<ul id="item1">
<ul id ="item2">
```

And try this :

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
   $("#instructionText").text("Instructions: choose an item");    
   $('#item1 .selected').removeClass('selected').remove().appendTo('#item2');
   $('#item2 .selected').removeClass('selected').remove().appendTo('#item1');
});

$("body").on("click","li", function(e) {
   $(this).toggleClass("selected");        
   $("#instructionText").text("Instructions: choose the item to change place with");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get index of list elemet and use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/FJt9X/2/

```
var swapElements = function(siblings, subjectIndex, objectIndex) {
    // Get subject jQuery
    var subject = $(siblings.get(subjectIndex));
    // Get object element
    var object = siblings.get(objectIndex);
    // Insert subject after object
    subject.insertAfter(object);
}
$(function() {
    swapElements($('li'), 0, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function swapItems(first, second) {
    var sibling = first.next();
    if (sibling.length) {
        first.insertBefore(second);
        second.insertBefore(sibling);
    } else {
        sibling = first.prev();
        if (sibling.length) {
            first.insertBefore(second);
            second.insertAfter(sibling);
        } else {
            var parent = firstItem.parent();
            first.insertBefore(second);
            second.appendTo(parent);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tLNAh/11/)

---

Edit: I updated the fiddle, now you have to click the button to swap items.